# Undefined property in ajax callback within controller property

Tags: ember.js, coffeescript

I have a login function on a controller and I can't figure out why the 'messageClass' and 'message' properties come up as undefined when I try to set them in the 'fail' callback on the post request. They set fine if I take them outside of the callback. I'm guessing it has something to do with the promises but I don't know why it wouldn't have access to the defined properties above. Any help is much appreciated.

```
App.UsersLoginController = Ember.ArrayController.extend
  message: ''
  messageClass: ''

  actions:
    login: ->
      email = @get 'email'
      password = @get 'password'

      url = "http://localhost:3000/api/v1/sessions/login"
      data = email: email, password: password

      request = $.post(url, data, (data)->
        console.log(data)
      ).fail((response)->
        @set 'messageClass', 'error'
        @set 'message', 'Wrong email or password'
      )
```

Comment: I totally spaced that the "this" context changed inside of the fail callback so it's not referring to the controller anymore.

Comment: @MatthewBlancarte That is phenom. I learn more about coffeescript every day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the fat arrow to fix that.

```
(data) =>
```

For non-coffee (my preference):

```
function (data) {
  this.doSomething(); // This function was cloned and returned with outer "this" context
}.bind(this)
```

Or:

```
var self = this;
function innerScope () {
  self.doSomething();  // outer "this" was cached as a variable.
}
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

I needed to reference the 'this' from outside the function like @MatthewBlancarte said above:

```
  request = Em.$.post(url, data, (data)=>
    Em.run =>
      @set 'messageClass', 'success'
      @set 'message', 'All GOOD!'
  ).fail((response)=>
    Em.run =>
      @set 'messageClass', 'error'
      @set 'message', 'Wrong email or password'
  )
```

The double arrow makes it so the function is referencing the 'this' of the controller.